# I encountered a browserslist caniuse-lite error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, build-error

I'm facing a compilation issue with my project.

```
Compilation failed:
       Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
         npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

Firstly, I encountered a Browserslist error then i dii npm install browserlist. But it caused other errors.

However, after running `npm install`, I encountered another issue: "Cannot find package '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods'".

```
Compilation failed:
       node:internal/process/promises:289
                   triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
                   ^
       
       Error: Cannot find package '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods' imported from /tmp/build_d5ae6346/babel-virtual-resolve-base.js
```

I installed it using `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods`, but then i get this.

```
Compilation failed:
       Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
```

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

i ran these commands

```
npm i caniuse-lite@latest and npm i caniuse-lite browserslist@latest
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

running this fixed the issue for me.